Delete a row based on duplicate uuid values in a table with ~1000 columns
I have a BigQuery table with ~1000 columns and there should only be one row per uuid. Some duplicate data has crept in such that uuid has been inserted twice (and no more) where message_timestamp is also a duplicate. The other ~998 columns will have different values. It is a costly job to recreate the table so I'd like to be able to delete one of these duplicate rows, any one, it doesn't matter which.
The solution would be something like where there are two rows in this table with the same uuid and message_timestamp, delete either one of them. It seems straightforward but I am stumped.

May I ask why uuid does not have a "unique" index?
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_create_unique_index.asp

Can you not delete them both/all then re-add the u duplicated row(s)?

Recreating the table, which has many partitions, is not possible due to the processing cost.

We can create row key - json_string , which includes all table columns,
and use this value to distinguish between strings.
We don't have to list all the column names in the table.
TO_JSON_STRING(a), where a - table alias in query.
This key can be used for deleting duplicates.
See example. There 3 rows - difference in column email.
WITH mytable as(
  select 1 id,'code1' code,'description1' description,'abc1@mail.com' email, 'address:Client1' contacts,'cf35d47-0370-467f-b946-f2a1286d8fad'  uid
  union all
  select 1 id,'code1' code,'description1' description,'abc4@mail.com' email, 'address:Client1' contacts,'cf35d47-0370-467f-b946-f2a1286d8fad'  uid
  union all
  select 1 id,'code1' code,'description1' description,'abc3@mail.com' email, 'address:Client1' contacts,'cf35d47-0370-467f-b946-f2a1286d8fad'  uid
  )
, data AS (
  SELECT uid
    ,TO_JSON_STRING(a) AS jdata -- this is row key
    ,row_number()over(partition by uid order by TO_JSON_STRING(a))rn
  FROM mytable a
)
SELECT targ.email,src.* 
from mytable targ
left join data src  on src.jdata=TO_JSON_STRING(targ)

Output



email
uid
jdata
rn




abc1@mail.com
cf35d47-0370-467f-b946-f2a1286d8fad "
""id"":1,""code"":""code1"",""description"":""description1"",""email"":""abc1@mail.com"",""contacts"":""address:Client1"",""uid"":""cf35d47-0370-467f-b946-f2a1286d8fad""}"
1


abc4@mail.com
cf35d47-0370-467f-b946-f2a1286d8fad "
""id"":1,""code"":""code1"",""description"":""description1"",""email"":""abc4@mail.com"",""contacts"":""address:Client1"",""uid"":""cf35d47-0370-467f-b946-f2a1286d8fad""}"
3


abc3@mail.com
cf35d47-0370-467f-b946-f2a1286d8fad  "
{""id"":1,""code"":""code1"",""description"":""description1"",""email"":""abc3@mail.com"",""contacts"":""address:Client1"",""uid"":""cf35d47-0370-467f-b946-f2a1286d8fad""}"
2



Of course, this procedure is applied only to lines that are duplicates.
some like this
delete from  mytable targ
inner join data src  on src.jdata=TO_JSON_STRING(targ)
where rn>1


The solution here was hacky but it got the job done:

Select one of the duplicate rows per uuid, identified by ROW_NUMBER() and write them to a table rows_to_keep. Note some of the duplicates were duplicated across all columns in the table so we couldn't try to differentiate them.
Delete all rows from the table where it was one of the uuids with duplicates.
Insert the deduplicated rows from step 1.

The goal here was to remove duplicates but also not rewrite the table partitions because they are very big TB. This worked.
